# Read Azure Blob via Powershell

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-blob-storage, azure-data-lake, azure-cli

There are some files stored in Azure blob storage. I want to search a string in the latest file and work with that string later on via Powershell. Problem is - I can't directly read or search string, I have to download it first through Get-AzStorageBlobContent. I want to avoid download file. I want directly to search a string.

```
$storageAccountName = "resaibdplogsa2prod"
$container_name = "devops-tasks"
$context = New-AzStorageContext -StorageAccountName $storageAccountName -UseConnectedAccount
$blobs = Get-AzStorageBlob -Container $container_name -Context $context | sort @{Expression = "LastModified";Descending=$true}
$latestBlob = $blobs[0]
$getString_terraform = Select-String -Path $latestBlob -Pattern '_tool/terraform.*'
```

Last line giving me a obvious error
' Cannot find path 'C:\Users\jubaiaral\Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.Common.Storage.ResourceModel.AzureStorageBlob' because it does not exist. '

Comment: You are using the command Select-String wrong. You can not use -Path for a string. In your case the code needs to look like that: `"Value | Select-String -Pattern "Pattern"`. Additionaly you should specify what property you want to use of the of $lastblob. Otherwise it will always use the datatype (Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.Common.Storage.ResourceModel.AzureStorageBlob) of the object and not the value.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure whether what you want to achieve would work using the Az PowerShell modules.

Based on @guiwhatsthat's note on using `Select-String`, you could use the REST API though. Technically it is also downloading the blob (but not storing in a file) - here is an example.

*Authentication Part*

This uses applicationId/secret based authentication. The corresponding Service Principal would need to have the `Storage Blob Data Reader` role assigned as a minimum.

```
$requestMethod  = 'POST'
$requestHeaders = @{
    'Content-Type'  = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
}
$requestUri     = 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/'+$tenantId+'/oauth2/v2.0/token'
$requestBody    = @{
    client_id       = $applicationId
    grant_type      = 'client_credentials'
    client_secret   = $applicationSecret
    scope           = $storageAccountBlobEndpoint+'.default'
}

$request = Invoke-RestMethod -Method $requestMethod `
                             -Headers $requestHeaders `
                             -Uri $requestUri `
                             -Body $requestBody
```

*Read Blob and search for string*

```
$blobRequestMethod  = 'GET'
$blobRequestHeaders = @{
    'Content-Type'  = 'application/xml'
    Authorization   = $($request.token_type + ' ' + $request.access_token)
    'x-ms-date'     = $(Get-Date -AsUTC -Format 'ddd, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss') + ' GMT'
    'x-ms-version'  = '2021-04-10'
}
$blobRequestUri     = $storageAccountBlobEndpoint + $containerName + '/' + $blobName

$blobRequest        = Invoke-RestMethod -Method $blobRequestMethod -Headers $blobRequestHeaders -Uri $blobRequestUri

$blobRequest | Select-String -Pattern $searchString
```

Obviously, you would need to populate some variables before running this (values below are random examples):

```
$tenantId                   = "597d8458-6a5d-447f-875d-922e448f681a"
$subscriptionId             = "3338781b-426a-4b1c-8545-d9b88d78039d"
$storageAccountBlobEndpoint = "https://<some_name>.blob.core.windows.net/"
$applicationId              = "4e625cb8-595b-4b46-9ba9-6a9d220f4208"
$applicationSecret          = "<some_secret_value>"
$containerName              = "container01"
$blobName                   = "yourblob.txt"
$searchString               = "find this"
```

I know it is not without downloading data but at least it is not writing a file. :-)

Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/get-blob