# How to read content from a CSV or text from ADLS Gen2 location using powershell without downloading that file?

Tags: azure, powershell, csv, blob, azure-data-lake

I have a use case where I have to read some files from Blob.. but I am unable to do it..I am only getting the Metadata. How to do the same without download the file and importing?

Get-AzDataLakeGen2ItemContent

Comment: AFAIK, you will be downloading file as the PowerShell command works that way

Comment: @RithwikBojja can't we read the blob file directly.

Comment: no as of my knowledge as I always get the file downloaded

Comment: Agree - you would need to download the content first. Here is a thread about Blobs along the same lines: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73887937/read-azure-blob-via-powershell/73891648#73891648

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree the discussion in the comments, there is no way you can read the blob directly from the blob storage. You need to download the blob locally and then read the contents from it using `Import-CSV`. Below is the complete code.

```
$context = New-AzStorageContext -StorageAccountName "<STORAGE_ACCOUNT_NAME>" -StorageAccountKey "<STORAGE_ACCOUNT_KEY>"

$blobName = "input.csv"
Get-Content (Get-AzStorageBlobContent -Context $context -Container "container" -Blob $blobName)

Import-CSV -Path $blobName
```